# Capture iframe window response and send to parent window

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I have a html page with an iframe like this

```
<html>
 <body>
    <iframe height="300px" width="100%" src="https://.......">
   </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

This works and I see the page mentioned in `src` attribute of iframe. This page is basically a third party login page. I can provide a callback url to the third party login url which is called on successfull login.

This callback url is my backend endpoint which is getting called. From my backend I return a new url. Now I want my whole window(not just the iframe) to be redirected to this url returned from my backend system.

I am not sure how to catch the value returned from my backend system.

I have read articles on how to pass value from iframe to parent window. I am thinking of passing the url to the parent window and load that using `window.location.href`.

I am stuck on how to capture the value returned from my backend system.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: maybe this can help - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: thanks @zmii. this links talks about the communication between iframe and parent window. As I said, I understand how to do this part. My question is how to capture the response sent from my backend in iframe, since I cannot control the iframe content

Comment: you can be polling iframe content if you know response from backend will change something in the iframe body or maybe attach event listener to iframe url change (if such exists). apart from it I can't imagine anything.

but you can also have some socket or polling solution on your webpage to hit your backend to see if appropriate action was already done (you will need to create custom endpoint or implement web socket for this).